# java: dynamic class cast

Tags: java, shell

I am writing a shell implementation in java which supports adding new commands by adding a `Command` object to a `Map<String, Command>` and writing the class associated to this command .

```
commandList.put("sort", new sort()); // sort extends Command
```

Each commands have multiple `OptionsDefinition<T>`s which associates an option name to a method reference using a `Consumer<T>` object (T is the class of the command : sort for example).

I want to make the methods referenced **non-static** in order to be able to call the same command twice in my shell without mixing the value of the same command's attributes so I need to pass `this` of type `sort` to the `Consumer<sort>` in the example of my sort command.

I want to know how I can transform what I have :

```
Command sort = commandList.getCommand("sort");
```

to that :

```
sort sort = commandList.getCommand("sort");
```

to be able to use

```
option.getCallback().process(sort); // sort is the reference to this
```

Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: If you only have one implementation of `sort` I would just use that one implementation, no need to look it up.  If you have multiple implementations I would use a cast.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement getCommand with an implicit cast.

```
public <C extends Command> C getCommand(String name) {
    return (C) commands.get(name);
}
```

Then you can write

```
Sort sort = commandMap.getCommand("sort");
```

Notes:

- classes are in TitleCase
- a List is a collection ordered and indexed by a non negative number. In Java you would call a collection indexed by a key, a Map.
- you will get an unchecked cast warning in the method because the compiler don't know if the cast is safe. What you can do to turn this off is

To suppress the warning.

```
public <C extends Command> C getCommand(String name) {
    @SuppressWarning("unchecked")
    C c = (C) commands.get(name);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: I get an unchecked cast warning when doing `return (C) commands.get(name);` , is that normal ?

Comment: @MaxV37 yes. The compiler doesn't know the cast is safe. Only you do.

Comment: @MaxV37 You can suppress the warning, see above.

Comment: I think you solution is not what I wanted because in my `CommandLauncher` class, I need to be able to call the method `option.getCallback().process(sort)` without specifying that sort is of type `Sort` with `Sort sort = commandMap.getCommand("sort");` because my command launcher has to work with any command

Comment: Because the reference to this needs to be of type `Sort` in the case of my sort command, I can't just pass it a `<C extends Command>` either I think.

Comment: So you need `option.getCallback().process(commandMap.getCommand("sort"));` ?

Comment: that was it, I thought it didn't work but I was wrong, thank you  very much !